# "mysql_config not found" when trying to install PHP 7.2 from sources

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, installation, lamp

On Ubuntu, I've got currently installed from sources Apache 2.2.32 + PHP 5.4.45 + mySQL 5.1.55. And now, I want to install PHP 7.2.16.

I downloaded the .tar.gz file, and tried to do the 'configure' of PHP:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php_7.2.16 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql --with-gettext --with-curl
```

(it worked with PHP 5.4, with another directory, obviously)

However, I get now the following error message:

```
mysql_config not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the mysql distribution
```

Must I reinstall the mySQL from scratch or is there any workaround to avoid this? Thank you.

Comment: I've read the manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php), and found that I have to indicate the path for the 'mysql_config'. I tried:

sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php_7.2.16 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysql_config --with-gettext --with-curl

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_config is installed via mysql-devel. If you run the mysql_config it should return to you all the options for compiling clients. If you install it from package, it should be somewhere like /usr/bin/mysql_config.
And when source compiling php you can pass the path of mysql_config under

```
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```